# Use JS script only in master page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a page with a master page.  Master page has lots of jQuery references, but one of them is conflicting, namely the core.js file.  Normally I would just remove the reference from master page and use the reference as needed at page-to-page bases, however I need this core.js file in the master page because master page itself has a module that uses it.  Thus, this core.js file is now visible by all children pages.  I tried adding the older version of the file as a reference to the problematic aspx by using a different file name (core.old.js) page but no luck, it just inherits the master page's core.js.  Does anyone know a way how I can add a reference to the master page that is exclusive to just the master page and no children pages?

Comment: have you tried jquery.noconflict ??

Comment: +1 was thinking the same thing

Comment: Not sure that will work, that just relinquishes jquery controls, but I need them.  You see core.js is actually part of jquery, just an older version of the core file.

Comment: Maybe you can nullify / overwrite the `Core` object in the page. Just after core.js loads.

Comment: How would I nullify a reference?  It's basically <script src="Scripts/jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  This one is in the master page and causing problems with another page, where I need to use jquery.ui.core.old.js

Answer (score 0):

Set `var page = 'master';` in the master view and then add an `if () {}` to your JavaScript that will only be executed if `page === 'master'`.

Comment: I'm sorry I am confused.  Set var = 'master' inside the master page? I may as well set it as a constant true because that variable will always get populated because it's on the master page.  I am clearly missing something.

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/ethagnawl/4070926) what I'm suggesting as it applies to Rails. Maybe it'll help you...